# Appending URL via href - more than once on same page

Tags: php, html

I have two menus, and I'd like each to be able to append the URL and stack these appends. Is this achievable via PHP and HTML alone?

So for instance, when a user clicks a selection in the first menu, the url would be append with "?variable=example" and the link would look like:

```
<a href="?variable=example">
```

But I'd like the user to also be able to select something from the second menu and for that to add "?variable2=example2" or "&variable2=example2" if it is the second selection the user has made. If I make the links in the second menu "&variable2=example2" it appends to the base url which is not what I want.

The tricky part is that I'd like the users to be able to start from either menu. Can this be done without Javascript?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in pure HTML. There's no way for HTML to do things differently depending on the original URL, that requires programming.

Comment: _"when a user clicks a selection in the first menu, the url would be append with "?variable=example" and the link would look like:"_ :  you need JS for this

Comment: I wrote [a small URL-manipulation library](https://gist.github.com/JaxoDI/e066638ba1e76642e2c9) a short while back, and it can do this.  You would want to use `url.setParam("variable", "example")`

Comment: Thank you all for the fast and helpful responses. For the time being I'm going with a different page flow as a quick workaround, but will eventually utilize JS for this to offer the experience I want for our users. I appreciate the link to your library Scott!

Answer (score 0):

While I am pretty sure that you can do this in plain PHP, it will be a bit of an arduous and obtuse process.  This is a task that JavaScript really is meant for, but if you are really determined to just do this via PHP, then you probably will have to store the URL in a cookie. Have your menus each read in and then modify that cookie and then do a POST request.  The big issue is that each menu will have to refresh the page since you would have to read in the cookie, then rewrite the cookie each time you wanted to make a change to the URL.  PHP does not really maintain a "state," or "memory," PHP just sends and receives requests.

While you can do all the typical programming operations in PHP, again the issue is maintaining state between PHP requests.

For anything that is not server related and in semi-real-time, you really should use JavaScript as this is the correct application for it (AJAX would be even better).  PHP really should be left for interfacing with servers.

Comment: `The only way to retain data between PHP requests is through the URL or a cookie.`. This wrong you can use sessions/memcache/.. to store the state of a request

Comment: Thank you Addison for the explanation. I'm just getting my feet wet here and this is helping me to understand the best use for PHP and JS. I appreciate your help. Thanks DarkBee for the clarification as well!